# Use grep to list the files a directory that were changed less that 10 hours ago

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I found this exercise from [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_04_05.html)

Make a list of files in your home directory that were changed less that 10 hours ago, using grep, but leave out directories.

It seems trivial to use `find` command, but how do I use `grep` command to find files that were changed within last 10 hours?

Thanks!

Comment: You... wouldn't. Use `find`.

Comment: Presumably the intent is that you pipe the output of `ls -l` (or similar) to `grep`. Which, by the way, is bad practice: you're right to suggest `find` instead. This may be a good educational exercise for becoming comfortable with the Unix utilities, but it's not a good idea to parse the output of `ls` in a "real" script, because Unix-like systems typically put very few restrictions on legal filenames.

Comment: @ruakh even if I pipe the output to grep, I still have no idea how to process the timestamps.

Comment: The exercise is defective.  This is like asking, "How do I use grep to learn more about Bolivia?"  You can, but you shouldn't.

Comment: @CodeNoob: Er, good point. I was assuming there was some option to `ls` that would present timestamps in some form that could be used for this, but looking through `man ls` and `info ls` (and `man date` and `info date`), I don't see one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is taken from the **Bash Guide for Beginners**, *Chapter 4. Regular expressions*. It is not a practical question, it's obviously going for exercising regular expressions, in a somewhat twisted way. Furthermore, the book is hosted on The Linux Documentation Project's site, so it is probably safe to assume to implement this in Linux, using the GNU implementation of the usual tools.

Here's my solution, using `grep` (a little bit):

```
ls -algG --time-style=+%s | grep ^[^d] | awk -vlimit=$(date +%s -d '10 hours ago') '$4 > limit { print substr($0, index($0, $4) + length($4) + 1) }'
```

Explanation:

- The `ls` options are to list all files including hidden ones (`-a`), use the long format (`-l`), omit owner and group information (`-g`, `-G`), and format times as if interpreted by `date`, `%s` means seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
- The `grep` matches lines that start with other than the letter "d", effectively excluding directories
- We pipe this to `awk`, because quite frankly there's no reasonable way to bend regular expressions for matching dates that stand for "less than 10 hours ago"

In the real world, I would solve this problem like this, NOT using regular expressions:

```
touch marker.touch -d '10 hours ago'
find . -newer marker.touch -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay, this is an abomination, but it is an exercise and I was curious.  The regex is likely too simple, but it works in my test case.  The "trick" here is that I'm using "stat" instead of "ls".  With "stat", you can request particular fields ( including last modified date ) and format the output.  Here I'm grabbing the current timestamp, going back 10 hours and then funneling stat formatted for mode in string form, modified date timestamp and filename through grep:

```
sh-3.2$ date "+%s"
1373170496

sh-3.2$ bc
bc 1.06
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type `warranty'. 
1373170496-36000
1373134496

sh-3.2$ stat -f"%Sp %m %N" * | grep "^[\-].*13731[3-7][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].*$"
-rw-r--r-- 1373168941 fileAB
-rw-r--r-- 1373168944 fileAC
```

Where fileAB and fileAC are two empty files I touched for some representative data.  The matches show the stat output, which is better explained by man pages.